# When to use abort(404) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception

I am wanting to create a registration verification,

So far I have planned out, that my Users table should have a `confirmation_code` column, and an `confirmed` column. The confirmed column has a default value of 0 (boolean false).

I create the new User from registration and assign them a `confirmation_code`.

I then email them a link to the verify route, which expects this `confirmation_code` in the query string.

The method which handles the verify request will be checking to see if the query string parameter (confirmation_code) exists.

My question is :

If the `confirmation_code` is absent, should I use the `abort(404)` method? Or throw a custom exception?

```php
public function verify($confirmation_code)
{
    if ( ! $confirmation_code ) {

        // abort(404)?
        // or,
        // throw new Exception?
}
```

Some feedback on when to use the abort method would be appreciated too.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually your choice to choose what type of error handling and error logging you implement in your project.

As advice, I will say that using custom exceptions for missing field exceptions. is a better idea. You can read more about a 404 error in the given link:

[404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).

Also refer to laravel documentation for more details regarding error logging.